# finding the probability density function of $ dY_t = - Y_t X_t dW_t$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Could someone point me to where I can learn how to derive the stationary distribution for the martingale $Y_t$ which itself has stochastic volatility drive by $X_t$:

\begin{align}
dY_t &= - Y_t\ X_t\ dW^Y_t  \\
dX_t &= - \kappa X_t dt + \sigma dW^X_t  
\end{align}

where the brownians $W_t^Y$ and $W_t^X$ are uncorrelated. Many thanks in advance !

Comment: i don't think martingales can have (non-trivial) stationary distributions.  If they converge in distribution optional stopping tells you that they want to be constants.  There is a square-root model, maybe hanson is the name, where you can find the distribution explicitly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I can give a reference for this particular question, but it can be done easily enough.

If the two Brownian motions are independent you can find the probability distribution for $Y_t$ conditioned on a path of $X_t$. You can write
$$ \log Y_t = \log Y_0 - \int_0^t X_t dW^Y_t - \frac12 \int_0^t X_t^2\,dt. $$
The point is that $\int_0^t X_t^2\,dt = Z_t$ is just a random variable and, conditioned on a particular path of $X_t$, the first integral is an Ito integral of a deterministic function, so
$$ \log Y_t = \log Y_0 - N(0, Z_t) - \frac12 Z_t.$$
So the distribution of $\log Y_t$ conditioned on the value of $Z_t=\int_0^t X_t^2\,dt$ is a normal distribution, as above, and the distributions of $X_t$ and $Z_t$ you can calculate independently of this question.

The particular $X_t$ that you wrote down is an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein%E2%80%93Uhlenbeck_process), for example, which also gives the pdfs for $X_t$, $X_t^2$, etc., from which you can find the distribution of $Z_t$.

Comment: I thought it would be harder. So doing ito and making the substitution $Z_t = X_t^2$ we recover a square-root process \begin{equation*}
dZ_t = \kappa_Z ( m_z - Z_t ) dt + \sigma_Z \sqrt{X_t} dW_t \end{equation*}The conditional distribution of this CIR process is then a non-central chi-squared.

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd want to do this, the simpler way is just to show that the distribution of $X_t$ for fixed $t$ is normal, and it also has a closed form in terms of $W_u^X$.  Also, your $Z_t$ is not the same as the $Z_t$ I used.

Comment: sure - I've corrected that (thanks). I'm missing something though:I solve for $X_t$ in terms of $W_t^X$. Then solve for $X_t^2$ and compute the distribution for $Z_t$. Finally, to obtain the conditional distribution for $Y_T$ I would need to joint probabilities of $X_t$ and $Y_t$ no? Even if they have independent Brownians

Comment: I don't know if there is a nice form for the distribution of $\int_0^t X_u^2\,du$ (you could do it numerically, of course; you get an SDE for it if you write $dZ_t=X_t^2\,dt$). You can write the joint distribution as $P(Z_t,Y_t)=P(Y_t|Z_t)P(Z_t)$, where $P(Y_t|Z_t)$ is normal. (Also, note that $Y_t$ depends not just on $X_t$ but its entire history, through $Z_t$.)